# Can a single schema.ini definition cover multiple files

Tags: c#, csv, schema

I have defined a schema.ini file for a CSV file, but I have multiple CSVs which I would like to use the same definition for as they are a sequence.

I.e

```
File0.csv
File1.csv
File2.csv
File.etc.csv
```

My schema would be something like:

```
[File*.csv]
Format=Delimited(,)
ColNameHeader=True
col1="Brand Code" Text
col2=Description Text
col3="Display Sequence" Text
```

Comment: It would appear the above * idea doesnt work, does anyone have a better suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell this isn't possible

-****************
In fact it's posible, you can do it in this way.

```
[file1.csv]
FORMAT = Delimited(#)
ColNameHeader = True
MaxScanRows=10
Col1=...
Col2=...
ColN=...

[File2.csv]
FORMAT = Delimited(#)
ColNameHeader = True
MaxScanRows=10
Col1=...
Col2=...
ColN=...
```

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

You can define and write the schema in your module/sub routine according to file format that want to be uploaded. This module/sub routine must be run/call to create schema before you run upload..
(my sample is using VB6)

Note : - Filenametxt is File name that want to be uploaded

```
IntFileHandleLog = FreeFile
Open App.Path & "schema.ini" For Output As #IntFileHandleLog
Print #IntFileHandleLog, "[" & FileNameTxt & "]"
Print #IntFileHandleLog, "Format=FixedLength"
Print #IntFileHandleLog, "MaxScanRows = 0"
Print #IntFileHandleLog, "CharacterSet = OEM"
Print #IntFileHandleLog, "Col1=" & """" & "Name" & """" & "Text Width 20"
Print #IntFileHandleLog, "Col2=" & """" & "PHONE_NUM" & """" & " Text Width 30"
Print #IntFileHandleLog, "Col3=" & """" & "PHONE_TYPE" & """" & " Text Width 20"
Print #IntFileHandleLog, "col4=" & """" & "UserName" & """" & " Text Width 20"
Print #IntFileHandleLog, "col5=" & """" & "A_STAT" & """" & " Text Width 10"
Print #IntFileHandleLog, "col6=" & """" & "B_STAT" & """" & " Text Width 10"
Print #IntFileHandleLog, "col7=" & """" & "RETRY" & """" & "integer width 2"
Print #IntFileHandleLog, "col8=" & """" & "Birth_Date" & """" & " double width 14"
Print #IntFileHandleLog, "Col9=" & """" & "Joint_Date" & """" & " double width 14"
Close #IntFileHandleLog
```